# problems using HL-2170W brother wireless printer

Tags: wireless-networking, printer

the printer is plugged into a belkin 54g wireless router. none of the computers see it. it's a pain and doesnt work and never worked. when i force it from its own button to print a test page it gives good results but im unable to print from any of my computer. does anyone have experience with this? maybe someone can follow through some settings with me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you can connect your printer WITHOUT installing any bloatware

**1) Connect Up**

1. Plug the printer into the wall and into your router via a network cable.
2. Connect your computer to the same network (wireless or wired, it doesn't matter)

**2) Restore Factory Defaults (If you're like me, you messed everything up and needed to reset)**

1. Turn Printer Off
2. Hold down the GO Button (the big one in the corner on the top)
3. Turn on Printer
4. When Toner, Drum and Error Lights are lit, release GO button
5. Press GO Button 7 times
6. Wait forever until lights come back on
7. Once the printer has started up again, cycle power for good measure

**3) Reserve the printer an address on your router. This will spare you gray hairs knowing that it will always be at the same address in wired ethernet mode.**

1. Open your browser and go to your router's ip address (eg. `http://192.169.1.1`). If you don't know your router's ip address, you'll have to Google the make and model.
2. Login to the router. Again if you don't know the login/password, the default login/password can be Googled. If they don't work you may need to reset your router to factory settings (that's a separate discussion).
3. Reserve an ip address for the printer. How to do this will vary between router models but an option usually exists under LAN Settings or the like. (For details see your router's manual) On my Netgear, it's "LAN Settings" > "Address Reservation" > "Add" > (Select Printer) > (Adjust Values **AND WRITE THE IP ADDRESS DOWN**) > "Add" > "Apply"

**4) Configure Wireless Settings Via Your Browser**

1. In your browser, enter your printer's IP address (eg 192.168.1.13)
2. Click "Network Configuration"
3. The default username and password are "admin" and "access"
4. Click "Configure Wireless"
5. Next To "Wireless Network Name (SSID)" Click Browse.
6. Select your network then click "OK"
7. Enter your network settings.
8. For WPA-PSK [TKIP] + WPA2-PSK [AES], Select "Infrastructure Mode". (I used TKIP Encryption Mode and it worked for me)
9. Hit Submit
10. Follow the prompt to remove your network cable from the back of the printer.
11. Check the "Attached Devices" page on your router to see if the printer connects wirelessly.
12. Give it at least 5 minutes (The thing is terribly slow)
13. To try different settings, plug the network cable back in and go to step 4.1